# @Converter annotated class not getting auto detected in spring-boot project

Tags: spring, hibernate, type-conversion, spring-boot, jpa-2.1

I am using spring-boot 1.2.2 with hibernate.version:4.3.6.Final for a simple operation and was using the @Converter for mapping java8 LocalDateTime field to timestamp.

In my converter class, I used autoApply=true as below.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter implements
    AttributeConverter {
    @Override
    public java.sql.Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime entityValue) {
        return Timestamp.valueOf(entityValue);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(java.sql.Timestamp databaseValue) {
        return databaseValue.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

However, I still have to use the @Convert on my entity.
The converter class is part of the packages I scan.
Is it something that I have to do to get this to work automatically without using the @Convert on all DB entries?

::Additionally::

Here is my DB Config

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    lef.setPackagesToScan("path to domain and Converter class");
    lef.afterPropertiesSet();
    return lef;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
    adapter.setShowSql(false);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    return adapter;
}
```

Comment: And `@Converter` is what? Spring only detects `@Component` annotated beans (or beans annotated iwth a annotation that itself is annotated with `@Component`  like `@Service`.).

Comment: Agreed @M.Deinum but I am configuring hibernate also and has defined the packages for Hibernate to scan. I have also updated the question with my Database and Hibernate Config class. I am guessing, I am missing something... I am not sure what it is?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot why configure everything by hand. But again what is `@Converter` if it isn't a `@Component` it doesn't do anything. Also hibernate probably needs to know about it instead of spring.

Comment: I agree, but I don't know how to make hibernate aware of this converter. Is there a way to tell hibernate to embed this converter to the list of converters it already has..?

Comment: You can use `@EntityScan` and give it a list of packages to scan for Hibernate. You can include the package where your JPA entities are as well as the package for the `Converter`. Then there is no need for the custom configuration anymore (unless you require it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I can see is you may need to change this line below

```
public class LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter implements
AttributeConverter<java.sql.Timestamp, LocaleDateTime>
```

Therefore, Spring would know how to automatically convert which type of attributes.

Comment: Thank you ... This was indeed the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

The order is incorrect, it should be:

```
public class LocalDateTimePersistenceConverter implements 
  AttributeConverter<LocaleDateTime, java.sql.Timestamp>
```

As the Javadoc states:

```
javax.persistence.AttributeConverter<X, Y>
Parameters:
  X the type of the entity attribute
  Y the type of the database column
```